# Display an icon based on a span class?

Tags: html, css

I am using a PHP template that shows hundreds of events.

Each event is in a county and I have country flags (as a SVG icons).

What I would like to do is display the flags for each listing, and I am thinking that a solution could be to display the icon WHEN the span class is displayed....

For example, this is the current code:

```
<span class="fwpl-term fwpl-term-germany fwpl-tax-country">
  <a href="https://my-url.com/country/germany/">Germany</a>
</span>
```

As you can see there is a class in the span called "fwpl-term-germany" so clearly, that is for Germany. I am hoping that this could then be used to insert this line:

```
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-germany"></span>
```

So that the end result is like this:

```
<span class="fwpl-term fwpl-term-germany fwpl-tax-country">
 <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-germany"></span> <a href="https:/my-url.com/country/germany/">Germany</a>
</span>
```

Would this require a ton of JavaScript or could it be done by a "display" function using CSS?

Thanks for all tips/pointers

Comment: Are you sure you need to insert a new `<span>`? Why not use the `::before` pseudo-element on `span.fwpl-term` ?

Comment: @Dai yes sure, no issue at all...just the challenge I find is how to trigger the icon to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to add a new `<span>` element: you can target the existing country-specific `<span>` elements and add the flag to their `::before` pseudo-elements, like so:

```
span.fwpl-term.fwpl-tax-country {
    
}
span.fwpl-term.fwpl-tax-country::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: ''; /* This is needed for ::before to be rendered at all. */
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

span.fwpl-term.fwpl-tax-country.fwpl-term-germany::before {
    background-image: url("germany.png"); /* Use `background-image:` not `background:` so you don't overwrite the inherited background-* properties. Also consider adding these flag images as inline `data:` URIs to reduce HTTP requests. */ 
}
span.fwpl-term.fwpl-tax-country.fwpl-term-france::before {
    background-image: url("france.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var flagIcons = $(".flag-icon");
  for(var i = 0; i < flagIcons.length; i++){
    var current = flagIcons[i];
    var cclass = $(current).attr("class");
    var country = cclass.substring(cclass.lastIndexOf("-")+1);
    $(current).replaceWith("<span class=\"fwpl-term fwpl-term-"+country+" fwpl-tax-country\"><span class=\"flag-icon flag-icon-"+country+"></span> <a href=\"https:/myurl.com/country/"+country+"/\">"+country+"</a></span>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-germany"></span>
```